# Microsoft Query SQL Current Date Optimization

Tags: sql, excel, microsoft-query

I use SQL in Microsoft Query to dump data from a server built on Progress into my Excel Tables. More recently, I've started to make these reports more robust by having the data change based on what day it is. My problem is that this increases the runtime massively. On one it takes a report that can run in under 10 seconds to over 2 minutes. In this example, I am pulling our sales records and looking at the day the order will ship and if it is in the future, I want to display 0 but if it is in the past I want it to display the units shipped. The field oeh_shp_date seems to be in the MM/DD/YYYY format so this is what I rigged together although it is not pretty. Any advice on how to speed this up would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
CASE
  WHEN ord_head.oeh_shp_date > RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(Cast(Month(CURDATE()) as CHAR(2))),2) + '/' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(Cast(DayOfMonth(CURDATE()) as CHAR(2))),2) + '/' + Cast(Year(CURDATE()) as CHAR(4)) then 0
  ELSE oe_ast.oel_plan_units
END AS 'UnitsShipped'
```

Comment: use `WHEN Date.FromText(ord_head.oeh_shp_date ) > CURDATE() THEN 0`

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to enable a decent answer.  Please add your full query details and the associated table structures to your question.  Information about what indexes are available over the Progress tables would also be useful.  As an initial suggestion, have you looked into the possibility of using pass-through queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your querying a postgresql database, standard postgresql functions such as **to_date** *should* work.  Go ahead and try the following:

```
CASE
  WHEN to_date(ord_head.oeh_shp_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') > current_date THEN 0
  ELSE oe_ast.oel_plan_units
END AS UnitsShipped
```

The only thing that is strange to me is that it appears your query isn't Postgresql query language.  For example **CURDATE** isn't a function.  **CURDATE** is a function in MySql, so maybe you've gotten the server type wrong?  If so, then try this:

```
CASE
  WHEN str_to_date(ord_head.oeh_shp_date, '%m/%d/%Y') > curdate() THEN 0
  ELSE oe_ast.oel_plan_units
END AS 'UnitsShipped'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I assumed my database was postgresql but after some research, it appears that Progress Open Edge has its own (ancient) flavor of SQL. It accepts the CURDATE function so your second suggestion was just what I needed to speed it up a bit. It's a shame our ERP software is built on something so old....but I digress. Thanks!